# Неправильная кодировка в error_log

Tags: php, apache, nginx

При записи в лог через error_log (PHP) неправильно отображает русскоязычную кодировку. Например, выводит:

```
Р”РјРёС‚СЂРёР№
```

Локальная сборка на OpenServer (Apache 2.4 + Nginx 1.14 + PHP 7.3), везде указана UTF-8, данные из базы также идут в UTF-8. Никаких проблем с кодировкой кроме error_log нет, тоже самое записывается в файл в нормальном виде.

Где может быть проблема?

Comment: Так а каким образом сменили кодировку? В каких настройках установили кодировку для лога ошибок?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, файл лога ошибок создавался в ASCII-кодировке. После принудительной смены кодировки на UTF-8 все стало отображаться как надо.